# Regular expression double brackets [[text]]

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regular expression: `(?<=\[\[)(.*?)(?=\]\])` for finding the pattern `[[some text inside]]`, and works, but I found a case where doesn't work: `[[[ some text]]]`.

I'm trying to find a solution, to only finding the pattern with double brackets in both sides like `[[]]` "exactly".

Comment: So you want to match `[[some text]]` but not `[[[some text]]]` is that correct? So `[[` followed by some characters, ending with `]]` but ignore anything with more than two `[[` or (presumably) two `]]`? Or do you still want to match the `some text` part in `[[[some text]]]`?

Comment: Like this ? http://regex101.com/r/lD3vK4

Comment: yes, I want exactly [[]], not for instance [[[]], or [[[[]]]]] etc...thanks for your help Matt, "sometext" means... either text or number like var char elements

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because SO is not a regex generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is, for selecting anything in between sets of `[` and `]` brackets:

```
((?!\])(?!\[).)+
```

[**Demo 1**](http://regex101.com/r/xQ3wX4)
eg.

```
var str = "[[[ some text]]]"
var res = str.match(/((?!\])(?!\[).)+/g);
console.log(res)
```

I think your edits made the question very different. Here is one that has strictly two starting and closing brackets.

```
^\[\[(((?!\[)(?!\]).)+)\]\]$
```

[**Demo 2**](http://regex101.com/r/nM3kM5)

You could use group 1 for selecting text only.

Comment: Thanks for your help Dhrubajyoti Gogoi but didn't work, I need exactly the pattern [[ Varchar or number ]], and get the content betewen this double brackets.

Comment: could you provide a sample string for which it does not work?

Comment: Are you aware that `(?:(?!\])(?!\[).)+` is equivalent to `[^\[\]]+`?  The only difference is that `.` doesn't match newlines.  If that's really your intent, you can use `[^\[\]\r\n]+` instead.

Answer (score 3):

I don't *think* you can make this work with the look-behind (besides, Javascript doesn't support look behinds anyway), but you could try this:

```
(?:(^|[^\[])\[\[)([^\]]*?)(?:\]\](?:($|[^\]])))
```

The second capture group will contain the text you want.

This matches,

```
 (^|[^\[])   start of string or NOT a `[`
 \[\[        two opening brackets
 ([^\]]*?)   any number of non closing brackets `]`
 \]\]        two closing brackets
 ($|[^\]])   End of the string or NOT a `]`
```

Example:

```
var reg = /(?:(^|[^\[])\[\[)([^\]]*?)(?:\]\](?:($|[^\]])))/;
var text1 = "[[some text]]"
var text2 = "[[[some other text]]]"

reg.test(text1);     // true
reg.test(text2);     // false

reg.exec(text1)      //["[[some text]]", "", "some text", ""]
reg.exec(text2)      // null
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex should work for you assuming there are no `[` or `]` characters between the double brackets.

```
(?<=\[\[)([^\[\]]*)(?=\]\])
```

[Demo on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/rU3xV0)

Comment: Thanks for your help Chirag64, but I need extacly the pattern [[ either character or number ]], for instance [[[ 55 AA ]]] is incorrect, I need to find the pattern with: [[ 55 AA, "inside either Varchar" ]], double brackets.

Comment: I misunderstood your question. You should refer to [Matt's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24043396/976897) since JavaScript doesn't support look-behind in RegEx, that seems like the only solution to your problem.